# T-SQL return ungrouped records making up sum

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, having

Using SQL Server 2008: I am trying to write a report of customer transactions which have occurred in the past week and which are above $1000. I have the following SQL query which will give me the correct records, but obviously aggregates the results:

```
SELECT 
   customerID, 
   CAST(createdAt AS DATE) AS transactionDate, 
   SUM(transactionAmount) as dailyTotal,
FROM transactions
WHERE createdAt > DATEADD( DAY, -7, GETDATE() )
GROUP BY clientID, CAST(createdAt AS DATE)
HAVING SUM(transactionAmount) > 1000
```

Resulting in something like:

```
| customerID | transactionDate | dailyTotal |
|       1    |      2013-11-01 |       1212 | 
|       2    |      2013-11-01 |      10002 |
...
|       1    |      2013-11-02 |       5212 |
```

However, I need to get the individual records which comprise these aggregated results, but obviously cannot omit the `GROUP BY` statement. Perhaps what I'm trying to achieve is not possible in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT t.customerID, 
       t.createdAt, 
       t.transactionAmount
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
       customerID, 
    FROM transactions
    WHERE createdAt > DATEADD( DAY, -7, GETDATE() )
    GROUP BY clientID, CAST(createdAt AS DATE)
    HAVING SUM(transactionAmount) > 1000
) a
ON a.customerID = t.customerID
WHERE t.createdAt > DATEADD( DAY, -7, GETDATE() )
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it solved my exact problem and the syntax was familiar.  The CTE example from marc_s is an interesting implementation also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a CTE with a `SUM` and an `OVER()` clause?

```
;WITH SalesAgg AS     
(
  SELECT 
     customerID, 
     TransactionDate = CAST(createdAt AS DATE), 
     TransactionAmount,
     TotalSum = SUM(transactionAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID, CAST(CreatedAt AS DATE) ORDER BY ClientID)
  FROM transactions
  WHERE createdAt > DATEADD( DAY, -7, GETDATE())
)
SELECT
   CustomerID, TransactionDate, TransactionAmount, TotalSum
FROM
   SalesAgg
WHERE
   TotalSum > 1000.0
```